# Cannot merge back into trunk, must be ancestrally related. But they *are* related as far as I understand

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So I'm trying to merge back into our trunk, but I'm getting errors saying that I can't do it because they're not ancestrally related. But I'm not clear on why that is. Here is the graph generated by TortoiseSVN

[image]

The trunk is in the bottom left (14698). Currently, I'm beginning with merging from the top right (15979) back into trunk. This one instance that claims it is not ancestrally related. There are some oddities in here that a co-worker introduced, and I'm not sure if it could be the cause of this. If you notice, right in the middle, the branch with revision number 15406 is actually branched from a Tag. This seems incredibly wrong to me, but I'm not sure. That's what the co-worker did a few months ago (he no longer works here).

Anyway, they *should* be all ancestrally related since they all come from trunk, right? If that's true, why am I getting this error? Would branching from a Tag cause this?

Comment: show real full command, used for merging-attempt

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I'm using tortoise (in the tags)

Comment: OK, miss it. *Try* to merge in command-line anyway

Answer (score 0):

- HEAD of trunk is 16063 (according to picture), not 14698
- Merge-source branch *seems to be related*, but you can|have to check it on **real repository**, not picture: `svn log -v -q --search trunk -l 1 BRANCH-URL` (far ancestor of branch, last trunk's revision)